# Wilcard matching substring in Python

Tags: python

I am completely new to Python and don't know how to get a sub-string which matches some wildcard condition from a string.
I am trying to get a timestamp from the following string:

```
sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671.data
```

I want to get only "*1360922654.97671*" part out of the string.
Please help.

Comment: Is there a set format these strings follow?

Comment: Yes, string follows something-something-something-something-REQDATA.something

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the dots and dashes have their specific function within your string, you can use this:

```
>>> s = "sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671.data"
>>> s.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('-')[-1]
'1360922654.97671'
```

Step by step:

```
>>> s.rsplit('.', 1)
['sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671', 'data']

>>> s.rsplit('.', 1)[0]
'sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671'

>>> s.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('-')
['sdc4', '251504', '7f5', 'f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5', '1360922654.97671']

>>> s.rsplit('.', 1)[0].split('-')[-1]
'1360922654.97671'
```

This will work for any strings in the form:

```
anything-WHATYOUWANT.stringwithoutdots
```

Comment: Wow, that was pretty quick and nice answer. It solved my problem. Thanks! Python is really very powerful.

Answer (score 6):

Because you mentioned wildcards you can use `re`

```
In [77]: import re   
In [78]: s = "sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671.data"
In [79]: re.findall("\d+\.\d+", s)
Out[79]: ['1360922654.97671']
```

Comment: heh, I was racing for the `re` module +1 for getting there first!

Comment: Thanks, this is more generic solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "sdc4-251504-7f5-f59c349f0e516894fc89d2686a0d57f5-1360922654.97671.data"
>>> s.split('-')[-1][:-5]
'1360922654.97671'
```

slightly fewer characters, only works where the last part of the string is `.data` or another 5 character string.